# Why do different EditForm. aspx display when opening list items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list with 5 content types.  I have 4 content types that are used when the item is first created.  However, once the item is created I always want the default content type to display in edit.aspx when the item is opened from the All Items view.

Unfortunately what happens when an item is click opened from the All List view is that it displays the last Content Type that was saved for the particular item.  Is there any way that I can always have the default content type display within the Edit.aspx form when opened from All Items view.

Again its worth noting once I am done creating the item I no longer need to view the item in any of the individual content types, but I do need to have all fields visible so any field can be edited within a form view.

I do realize that to see all fields all a user needs to do is select the parent content type I have from the Content Type drop-down within edit.aspx, but most users are stunned to see the form missing so many fields and think there is a problem.  They have no idea you can select various Content Types from the drop-down.  Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every item in SharePoint belongs to exactly one Content Type. And, as you already said, the forms will show the columns that are associated with the current Content Type. If you want to show columns from a different Content Type, you will have to change the Content Type. You can do that either with custom code or with a workflow.

Please see the accepted answer to a similar question:
[Sharepoint change Content Type in Sharepoint Designer using workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489477/sharepoint-change-content-type-in-sharepoint-designer-using-workflow)